# 'filesystem' is not a namespace type (C++ Error

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, gnuradio

I want to use filesystem library in C++ however, even though I include it in the following way, I get an error saying: "'filesystem' is not a namespace type":

```
#ifndef __has_include
static_assert(false, "__has_include not supported");
#else
#  if __has_include(<filesystem>)
#    include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
#  elif __has_include(<experimental/filesystem>)
#    include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
#  elif __has_include(<boost/filesystem.hpp>)
#    include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
#  endif
#endif
```

So it finds the filesystem header however, it does not recognize it.

Including <experimental/filesystem> directly causes to another error related to the toolkit (gnuradio) I am using, which is quite hard to explain. Therefore, I choose not the explain that part.

Running

```
$gcc --verison
```

gives the following output:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

 '''
```

This is a sample output when I run make with VERBOSE=1:

```
   /usr/bin/c++  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DBOOST_ATOMIC_DYN_LINK    -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_REGEX_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK -DGR_CTRLPORT -Dgnuradio_lkn_ncs_EXPORTS -I/home/name/folder/project/projectname/lib/../include  -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC   -fvisibility=hidden -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/gnuradio-lkn_ncs.dir/mac_controller_impl.cc.o -c /home/name/folder/project/projectname/lib/mac_controller_impl.cc
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: are you running `gcc` or `g++`?

Comment: I have edited the original post, I hope it answers your question. I am using the standard, cmake .. make commands to compile..

Comment: Have you set the C++ standard to 17? Try `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)`.

Comment: This could break the whole project. Apparently, I am still using C++11, which causes the error. I solved the issue by choosing the last option, by including <boost/filesystem>. Note that the first two did not working for me

Comment: To understand it correctly, you want to be able to compile your library with c++11, but you have the problem that even when c++11 is selected if still finds the `filesystem` header and does not fallback to `boost/filesystem` due to that?

Comment: Exactly. I think this leads to the error. Apparently, the project uses c++11 but still it includes <filesystem> even though it was introduced in C++17, according to my understanding.

Comment: @OnurA I think the problem was due to using `__has_include`, which was introduced with C++17. But you're using C++11.